# Navigating objects in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a [PHP proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) to make a cross domain JSON call, and I'm not sure how I should traverse the resulting object to get the property I want (circled in red in the screenshot below).

If try alert(json), it gives me `[Object object]`. Tried going through it by treating it as an array but that didn't seem to work either.

Any clues?

[image: object1]

This is what `console.log(json)` shows me:

[image: object2]

Comment: `alert` only displays strings. Use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
json.data.rows[0][3]
```

And, to get more information, use

```
console.log(json)
```

Comment: I did `console.log(json)` and have added the output to my original post. When I used `json.data.rows[0][3]`, I got the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined`

Comment: Ok, try json.content.data.rows[0][3]. If contents is an object inside of json, then that should work